# Sum of squared coefficients of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation

Let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots a_nx^n$ be a polynomial, and let $\mu$ be a constant.

Is there any way to write $$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2 \mu^i$$ as a function of $P(x)$ or related polynomials? Clearly the goal is to have everything as a function of $P(x)$ or similar polynomials so an answer like

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2 \mu^i = P(\mu)P(1) - 2\sum_{i < j}^na_ia_j\mu^i$$

won't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hadamard product of two polynomials  $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i  x^i$  and  $g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n b_i  x^i$ is called the polynomial  $f(x)*g(x)$ where 
$$
f(x)*g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_i x^i. 
$$
There is a representation the product in terms of contour integrals.

Let now $M(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n \mu^i x^i.$ 
Then
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2 \mu^i=(f(x)*f(x)*M(x)) \big |_{x=1}.$$

Comment: +1 Interesting, thanks! One can also write it as $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\mu^i = (f(x) * f(x))\mid_{x = \mu}$

Comment: yes, of cource.

Comment: I hope that for many cases  there exists a close expression for $f(x)*f(x).$

Comment: Yes, it is definitely worth a try in many occasions! :)